# What is the regular expression that matches the word 'Coal'?

Tags: r, regex

I'm using the grep command in R to find all occurrences of the word `Coal` in a column of a data frame. `Coal` can occur anywhere in the value. For example, `Coal Combustion` is also a valid value. What is the regular expression for this?

I've tried using:

```
grep("[:Coal:]", NEI[,5])
```

but it does not give me the right answers.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
grep("\\bCoal\\b", NEI[,5])
```

The `\b` part matches word boundaries so "Coal" can't be touching any other letters.

Comment: @Moon_Watcher traditionally we accept answers which solved our problems by clicking the green check mark next to the answer. This shows the question has been answered satisfactorily and is part of good site citizenship. Thanks.

Comment: @Simon O'Hanlon I know, but it wouldn't allow me to check the answer immediately. I had to wait for a while before I did that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
regmatches(subject, gregexpr(".*Coal.*", subject, perl=TRUE));
```

If you want to make sure Coal is not embedded in a word, just add boundaries:

```
grepl("\\bCoal\\b", subject, perl=TRUE);
```

Comment: This would match `subject<-"Coalescent Tree"` and i'm not sure that's what is intended.

Comment: @MrFlick You're right. Gave him a second option with boundaries. Thanks for pointing that out, I didn't pick that up from the question. :)

Comment: In R those need to be "\\b" to properly escape the slash.